# How to attach images in field collection to node using feeds

Tags: 7, media, feeds, entities

I'm using feeds and xpath_parser to import content to my site. I have two directories in my private directory called articles and photos. The xml is in the articles and the photos are in the photos. I have a content type called `articles` which has an unlimited field_collection containing `photo` and `caption`. When the feeds module parses the xml it will get a list of photos and captions that should attach to that field collection. Everything other than the images are working. The errors I get are:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Download of 8084413.jpg failed with code -1002.' in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsParser.inc:324

and

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid enclosure 8084413.jpg' in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsParser.inc:389

and

> Notice: Undefined variable: file in FeedsEnclosure->getFile() (line 388 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsParser.inc).

I'm using the latest dev versions of all modules involved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve your issue? I am getting the same `FeedsParser.inc:389` error that you show above.